# how to print structure value(like gdb ptype) automatically in C?

Tags: c, printing, structure

This question stay in my head for a long time.
    As we know, we can easily print data structure in GDB when we debugging, like gdb ptype command, it can output all field value of structure. I know GDB use bfd library to read symbolic information in object file.
    My question is: if I want to do this in my C source code, how to do? because I don't want to printf each field of structure one by one. Is there have any exist library to solve this issue?
    I think that library will not only meets my requirement, it will be very useful for many others programmers when writing C/C++ code.

Comment: What about the BFD library used by GDB?  You mention that's how your exemplar program does it - can you not use it too?  Otherwise, it is highly non-trivial.  You have to find out the layout of the data structures and then arrange to print them.  You either need a detailed description of the type in your code to pass to the library of your choice, or you have to work out how to read the debug information from the executables on your system.  Neither is trivial.

Comment: BFD library is too low level for this purpose, that's why I want a high level library to do this job. Actually GDB do a lot of things on BFD library to perform ptype operation, like you said, find out the layout of the data structure and arrange it. The question is GDB never export this functionality, if GDB provider this generic function library to user, then we will be more comfortable. :)

Comment: @user950917 You can't really do low-level stuff at high-level. CPUs don't run JavaScript directly (well, maybe nowadays they do...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux C: Easy & 'pretty' dump/printout of structs (like in gdb) - from source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311182/linux-c-easy-pretty-dump-printout-of-structs-like-in-gdb-from-source-co)

Answer (score 0):

As far as C is concerned, such a library cannot exist.

What you can do is write a compiler kind of tool that takes a `struct` description in some language and generates a header file with `struct` declarations in C, and a source file with printing code. Such tools do exist (e.g. protobuf-c), but they are mostly geared towards efficient binary serialization, not human-readable representation of C data.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there are such tools built for C which are widely used. However, you can try to write a function to take the burden and call it when needed. I know a function cannot print all sorts of structure and you've got to build each for each type of struct but it still is a better idea than to just stick to the old rule, write each time.