# Displaying struct values in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, gnu

In GDB, given a variable that points to a struct, `print` will display the raw pointer value and `x` will display the raw bytes pointed to. Is there any way to display the data pointed to as that struct, i.e. a list of fields and their values?

Comment: May be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466511/how-to-print-structure-valuelike-gdb-ptype-automatically-in-c

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
print *variable
```

If you do that it will display the value of that variable in GDB.
You also have an option to display the struct with indentation and new lines:

```
$1 = {
  next = 0x0,
  flags = {
    sweet = 1,
    sour = 1
  },
  meat = 0x54 "Pork"
}
```

For that you need to set the pretty print:

```
set print pretty on
```

If you want to print an array of values you do:

```
print *array@len
```

Comment: Yeah it prints the raw data but that still does not recognize the values as a struct. If i got it right, the question was about recognizing as a struct (i.e. recognize fields in the struct) which i don't think is possible

Comment: Your initial post (before edit) was only about print *array@len which can only print members of an array of same type. http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_9.html. However, the latter edit to the answer might be a solution. Thanks for adding that to my knowledge

Comment: Is it possible to print the struct with the typenames of each member as well?